# How to correctly update an entity with express and typeorm

Tags: node.js, api, express, typeorm

I'm looking for the best way to update a `User` entity with typeorm and express.

I have something like this (I have reduced, but there are many other attributes) :

```js
class User {
  id: string;
  lastname: string;
  firstname: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}
```

And I have a path to update user's attributes like :

```js
app.patch("/users/me", ensureAuthenticated, UserController.update);
```

Now (and it's my question), how to properly update the user? I don't want the user to be able to add themselves as an admin.

So I have :

```js
export const update = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const { sub } = res.locals.token;
  const { lastname, firstname, phone, email } = req.body;

  const userRepository = getRepository(User);
  const currentUser = await userRepository.findOne({ id: sub });

  const newUserData: User = {
    ...currentUser,
    lastname: lastname || currentUser.lastname,
    firstname: firstname || currentUser.firstname,
    phone: phone || currentUser.phone,
    email: email || currentUser.email
  };

  await userRepository
    .update({ id: sub }, newUserData)
    .then(r => {
      return res.status(204).send();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      logger.error(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Error." });
    });
};
```

With that, I'm sure to update the right attributes, and the user can't update admin. 
But I find it very verbose to create a new object and fill in the informations.

Do you have a better way to do it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can follow the [DTO pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object).

For example:

```
class UserDto {
    // define properties
    constructor(data: any) {
        // validate data
        ...
    }
}

const userDto = new UserDto(req.body);                                          

await userRepository
    .update({ id: sub }, userDto)
    .then(r => {
        ...
    })
    .catch(err => {
        ...
    });
```

The nestjs framework has a [good example](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-payloads) of how you can set up a DTO pattern generically. But it's easy enough to roll your own using [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) and [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) which will make the validation a lot more declarative.

Comment: But what about when you use Nest with TypeORM? Then entities and DTOs are separate classes and you need a way to merge your entities with the data from the DTOs before saving them with the repository.

Comment: Yes in that case you'll need to convert DTO classes into the entity classes before saving them.